# How to use contour integration to compute a **real** integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Suppose we are given:

$$\text{Evaluate} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \text{dx}$$

This is quite easy because you will notice that:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \text{dx} = \arctan(1) - \arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

But can this be done using complex analysis, contour integration?

Also, is this possible (using **contour integration?**)

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \text{dx}$$

Thanks!

Comment: I think contour integration is usually used to calculated $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But can this be done using complex analysis, contour integration?*

Of course! As it has already been suggested in the comments, use the symmetry of the integrand to rewrite the integral as $~\displaystyle\frac12\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2},~$ then choose $x=e^{it}$, where $t\in(-\pi,0)$, and notice that the denominator has roots in $x=\pm i\iff t=\pm\dfrac\pi2.~$ I believe you can take it from here. :-$)$

Comment: If you use that contour, since the root lies on the contour, the integral will not converge.

Comment: @DougM: And what do we usually do when such a situation arises ? (As one can safely infer from the answer's last sentence, the finishing touches are left to the reader, rather than being spoon-fed).